# Why is H gate called a ‘square-root of NOT’ gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, nielsen-and-chuang, hadamard

In Nielsen and Chuang, there's the following paragraph:
[image: > The H gate is sometimes described as being like a ‘square-root of NOT’ gate, in that it turns a |0> into (|0> + |1>)/ √ 2 (first column of H), ‘halfway’ between |0? and |1?, and turns |1? into (|0? − |1?)/ √ 2 (second column of H), which is also ‘halfway’ between |0? and |1?.]

I understand that
\begin{align*} \sqrt{NOT} =
\frac{1}{2}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
\sqrt 2 e^{i\pi / 4}&\sqrt 2 e^{-i\pi / 4}\\
\sqrt 2 e^{-i\pi / 4}&\sqrt 2 e^{i\pi / 4}
\end{array}} \right) \\
\end{align*}

But, I'm still confused how the H gate is related to the ‘square-root of NOT’ gate.

Comment: It is already explained in the paragraph you copied to your question. Hadamard is "like" square root in sense that turns a qubit to half-way between states $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. There is also stated that $H^2$ is not $X$. Hence there is no relation to square root of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the Hadamard gate is ever actually called "square root of NOT". I'd guess the emphasis in this sentence is on the word "*like*", in that it possesses the same property of converting the basis states into states halfway between the basis states, though the Hadamard gate does it without adding complex phases, and the $\sqrt{NOT}$ throws in complex numbers.